# How to build Dynamic Position Button if different Resolution or Device

Tags: flutter

I try create app using flutter but i have problame with test small device and large device. i need this button always 100 Margin from buttom like this[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
new ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints:
                        const BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity),
                    child: new RaisedButton(
                      child: new Text('Login'),
                      onPressed: _loginPressed,
                    )),
```